# Reorder a list 'in place', according to another list

Tags: python, list

How can I reorder a list in python according to another list, but without creating a new list, since it is linked by several objects?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6618515/sorting-list-based-on-values-from-another-list) question and it's answers create new lists, so they don't apply.

Comment: Use [slice assignment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10623302/how-assignment-works-with-python-list-slice).

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary - That will work fine for a list of integers (as the slice), but what if I have something different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create the list however you want, and then reassign the elements.  For example:

```
 X[:] = [x for (y,x) in sorted(zip(Y,X))]
```