# Unexpected extra zero in python list when assigned explicitly

Tags: python, list

I want the to directly populate particular sections of a list from a string that is returned by a function.
I want to do some binary arithmetic on these elements later.
When I access the list using subscript, the elements are not getting stored as I expect. A simplified version of my code is:

```
   reg_bin_list = ['0']*2
   reg_bin_list[0:1] = "10"

   print reg_bin_list
```

This puts an extra zero at the end: ['1', '0', '0']

Instead of that if do :

```
   reg_bin_list = "10"
```

Then the list is printed correctly as I expect i.e. `['1', '0']`

Can anyone help me understand when I access using the index operator, what is going on. Why am I seeing an extra zero at the end?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How assignment works with python list slice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10623302/how-assignment-works-with-python-list-slice)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is with your slicing. `[0:1]` starts from index `0` and ends before index `1`. Hence change the slice to `[0:2]`

```
>>> reg_bin_list = ['0']*2
>>> reg_bin_list[0:2] = "10"  # Note the change
>>> reg_bin_list
['1', '0']
```

> Why am I seeing an extra zero at the end?

It is the additional `0` left behind in the original list.

Do have a look at [Explain Python's slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/509211/4099593), for a nice explanation as to why.

Comment: A convenient way to remember this is that a slice `x[a:b]` has length `b-a`.

Answer (score 1):

When slicing a list using - `list[<start>:<stop>]` - the stop index is exclusive, that means it does not get included in the slice.

Hence, when you do -

```
reg_bin_list[0:1] = "10"
```

This is only taking the `reg_bin_list[0]` , and hence it is insert `'1'` and `'0'` starting at  0th position, leading to the 3 length list.

You should use -

```
reg_bin_list[0:2] = "10"
```

Example -

```
>>> reg_bin_list[0:2] = "10"
>>> reg_bin_list
['1', '0']
```