# Python, How to Define a Function whose input is a Variable in the Global Namespace it must then Alter

Tags: python, list, function

I have been learning to program in python, and came across this question which I have been struggling to solve. The question is as follows:

Write a function f(list, start, end) which takes as arguments a list and two indices and modifies the argument list so that it is equal to the result of the slice expression list[start:end]

I can write a function that splices the list for positive indices, ie:

```
def f(this_list, start, end):
    this_list=this_list[start:end+1]
```

But how do I get it to update whatever list the function is pointed to in the global namespace?

So, for instance, if I then get it to run:

```
x=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
f(x, 2, 4)
print x
```

it returns the originally defined x, not the updated. So this is because it has only updated the list in the function's namespace, yes? But then how can I get it to update x globally?

Comment: Homework question?

Comment: @bub Of course it is

Comment: One I found in a set of exercises, but not assessed homework

Comment: @leob It will still get the same response on StackOverflow. This website isn't appropriate for "can you write this for me" questions.

Comment: We're not going to *"provide a solution"*. Put some effort in; at least show what you've tried and be specific about how it fails (see [mcve]).

Comment: No worries, my attempt has been added, thanks!

Comment: Do a search on [Slice Assignment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10623302/how-assignment-works-with-python-list-slice). BTW, `list` is not a good choice for a variable name because it shadows the built-in `list` type.

Comment: Not sure what they're hoping to teach you. The trick to the question is to use only operations that work in place. Assignment doesn't work in place, so you can't use it.

Comment: You should definitely read [Ned Batchelder's Fact's and Myths about Python Names and Values](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html). Essentially, the problem is that assignment doesn't alter objects, it changes the objects that variables point to. Also, check out this [blog post](https://jeffknupp.com/blog/2012/11/13/is-python-callbyvalue-or-callbyreference-neither/) about Python's evaluation strategy - it is neither call by value or call by reference. It is technically known as [call by sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_sharing).

Comment: if you ___really___ need to update a variable in the global scope, use [`globals()['variable_name']= value`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#globals).

Comment: @Rawing: You're kidding, right? Using the `global` keyword is better than directly man-handling the `globals()` dict. But neither of those things are needed here.

Comment: Hopefully my previous hint led you to a solution. But if it didn't, give this a go: `this_list[:] = this_list[start:end+1]`

Comment: @PM2Ring The `global` keyword does something completely different.

Answer (score 0):

As someone already mentioned in the comments, you should definitely read [Facts and myths about Python names and values](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)

The simple solution to your problem is making a new value and returning it.
This will work :

```
def f(this_list, start, end):
    this_list=this_list[start:end+1]
    return this_list
```

Comment: I've just been having a read through it, it has helped remove some confusion. Is it possible to update the list globally without returning anything from the function, however? I know it probably sounds like little bit of a strange thing when returning the updated list is so simple, but simply out of interest is there some way to do it?