# Reference to an element in a list

Tags: python, random

I am a little confused about how python deal with reference to an element in a list, considering these two examples:

First example:

```
import random
a = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8]]
b = [0.1,0.2]
c = random.choice(a)
c[:] = b
print(a)
```

Second example:

```
import random
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
b = 0.1
c = random.choice(a)
c = b
print(a)
```

In first example, the content in list a is changed; while in the second example, the content of list a is not changed. Why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's start with the second case. You write

```
c = random.choice(a)
```

so the name `c` gets bound to some element of a, then

```
c = b
```

so the name `c` gets bound to some other object (the one to which the name `b` is referring - the float 0.1).

---

Now to the first case. You start with

```
c = random.choice(a)
```

So the name `c` gets bound to an object in `a`, which is a list itself. Then you write

```
c[:] = b
```

which means, replace all items in the list bound to by the name `c`, by some other list. In fact, this is called [slice assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10623302/how-assignment-works-with-python-list-slice), and is basically syntactic sugar for calling a method of the object to which `c` is bound.

---

The difference, then, is that in the first case, it doesn't just bind a name first to one object, then to another. It binds a name to a list, then uses this name to indirectly call a method of the list.

Comment: Is there a way to change the value of the list `a` in the second example?

Comment: Sure, if you do `i = random.choice(list(range(len(a)))`, then you'll get an index. Then `a[i] = ...` will modify it.