# Explain the usage of 'some_list[0:0] = new_list'

Tags: python, conventions

I encountered this code that is giving a long list of file paths but I am curious what the significance of the `[0:0]` part of the code is but I can't seem to find any references to this specific syntax usage.

Would `sys.path[0] =` mean the same thing as `sys.path[0:0]`? Is that even a thing?

Since I can't seem to find reference to this kind of code, does that mean there is a better way to do this in newer versions of Python? I ask because I suspect the application using this code was build on Python 2.4.

```
import sys
sys.path[0:0] = [
  '/home/nac/eggs/Pillow-2.7.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg',
...
...
...
 '/home/nac/eggs/pycparser-2.14-py2.7.egg',
]
```

Comment: It's what I would consider an unidiomatic way of doing `sys.path.insert(0, <whatever>)` Or rather, `for something in <whatever>: sys.path.insert(0, something)`

Comment: But basically, assignment to a list slice modifies the list in-place. This slice: `my_list[0:0]` is actually nothing, but if you assign to it, it inserts to the left-most place. If you assign to a slice too "far to the right" it essentially adds to the right-most part.

Comment: This is [Slice Assignment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10623302/how-assignment-works-with-python-list-slice)

Comment: Okay, great! Thank you for the responses.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is equivalent to an update/insert:

```
>>> numbers = [1, 2, 3]
>>> numbers[0:0] = [4, 5, 6]
>>> numbers
[4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3]
```

Another example:

```
numbers = [1, 2, 3]
>>> numbers[0:2] = [4, 5, 6]
>>> numbers
[4, 5, 6, 3]
```