# How to unpack inner lists of a nested list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, iterable-unpacking

Suppose we have a nested list like `nested_list = [[1, 2]]` and we want to unpack this nested list.
It can easily be done with the following (although this requires Python 3.5+):

```
>>> nested_list = [[1, 2]]
>>> (*nested_list,)[0]
[1, 2]
```

However, this operation unpacks the *outer* list.
I want to strips off the inner brackets but I haven't succeeded.
Is it possible to do such kind of operation?

The motivation might be unclear with this example, so let me introduce some background.
In my actual work, the outer list is an extension of `<class 'list'>`, say `<class 'VarList'>`.
This `VarList` is created by [`deap.creator.create()`](http://deap.readthedocs.io/en/master/api/creator.html#deap.creator.create) and has additional attributes that the original `list` doesn't have.
If I unpack the outer `VarList`, I lose access to these attributes.

This is why I need to unpack the inner list; I want to turn `VarList` of `list` of something into `VarList` of something, not `list` of something.

Comment: Isn't it podsible to just pass the inner list to the `VarList` initializer?

Comment: That's... not how unpacking works. First, the unpacking in `(*nested_list,)` doesn't help you; the `[0]` is doing all the useful work there. Second, for your desired unpacking to work, you'd have to create a `VarList`, not a `list`, and there's no syntactical support for doing that. There may be not-unpacking ways to do what you want, depending on the details of VarList and exactly what you want to preserve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to preserve the identity and attributes of your `VarList`, try using the slicing operator on the left-hand side of the assignment, like so:

```
class VarList(list):
    pass

nested_list = VarList([[1,2]])
nested_list.some_obscure_attribute = 7
print(nested_list)

# Task: flatten nested_list while preserving its object identity and,
# thus, its attributes

nested_list[:] = [item for sublist in nested_list for item in sublist]

print(nested_list)
print(nested_list.some_obscure_attribute)
```

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand why `nested_list = ...` yields different result (i.e., a list object). Is it related to list mutability?

Comment: Maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10623383/8747) will help explain the difference between `nested_list = ...` and `nested_list[:] = ...`

Comment: Thanks for the reference!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's possible with a slice assignment:

```
>>> nested_list = [[1, 2]]
>>> id(nested_list)
140737100508424
>>> nested_list[:] = nested_list[0]
>>> id(nested_list)
140737100508424
```