# convert a list of strings list into integers

Tags: python, list

could you help me please? I use Python 3.x and would convert this variable ex into an integers list.

```
ex = [['2003', '12', '27', '7', '8646'],
      ['2003', '12', '28', '7', '7645'],
      ['2003', '12', '29', '2', '12823'],
      ['2003', '12', '30', '2', '14438'],
      ['2003', '12', '31', '3', '12374']]
```

I tried with this function but it doesn't work properly:

```
liste = []

def function_int(x):
    for i in x:
        liste.append(int[i])
    return liste
```

Thanks you for your support!

Comment: `liste` shouldn't be global for starters. Then are you aware that your input is a list of lists? not just a list? what is your expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the fastest most memory efficient way of doing it in my opinion, note: it will overwrite `ex` if you want a new list then change `ex[:] =` to `liste =` or whatever you want to call your variable

```
try:
    #check out this module for faster string checking
    from fastnumbers import *
except:
    pass

ex = [['2003', '12', '27', '7', '8646'],
      ['2003', '12', '28', '7', '7645'],
      ['2003', '12', '29', '2', '12823'],
      ['2003', '12', '30', '2', '14438'],
      ['2003', '12', '31', '3', '12374']]

ex[:] = [[int(e) if e.isdigit() else e for e in sl] for sl in ex]
```

results:

```
for sublist in ex:
    print (sublist)

[2003, 12, 27, 7, 8646]
[2003, 12, 28, 7, 7645]
[2003, 12, 29, 2, 12823]
[2003, 12, 30, 2, 14438]
[2003, 12, 31, 3, 12374]
```

To explain slice notation, especially being used on the left of `=` please see this question: [How assignment works with python list slice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10623302/how-assignment-works-with-python-list-slice)

Comment: Thank you @new_to_code for your help. Your solution is an other way.

Answer (score 3):

You're actually halfway there. You need a *nested loop* if you want to tackle *nested lists*.

Something like this.

```
def function_int(ex):
    liste = []
    for i in x:
        liste.append([])
        for j in i:
        liste[-1].append(int(i))

    return liste
```

At each outer iteration, we append the next inner list to our outer list. At each inner iteration, append the converted integer value to the most recently appended inner list.

Also note that `int` is a function, you call it with parenthesis, not square braces.

---

Alternatively, you could do this with a list comprehension.

```
liste = [[int(y) for y in x] for x in ex]
```

Which is much more concise with minimal loss in readability.

---

Another possibility is the possiblity of `ValueError`s arising during conversion. You could take care of that only if you're working with the nested loop code. You'd use `try-except` handlers to do it.

```
try:
    liste[-1].append(int(i))
except ValueError:
    pass
```

Comment: @coldspeed, Thank you a lot.
This one print what a expected:

liste = [[int(y) for y in x] for x in ex]

Comment: I'm new here and don't yet know how to use the site. How can I vote? thanks.

Comment: @JoshBagwel Why did you unmark my answer? Please stick to a single answer _unless_ there's something wrong with it. You can't accept more than one answer.

Answer (score 1):

Along with the other answers, here is another approach that you can use:

```
integer_x = [list(map(int, each)) for each in x]
print(integer_x)
```

Comment: .Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @JoshBagwel No problem. Always happy to help. If you find it helpful, don't forget to vote.

Answer (score 1):

take a look at the **ast** module

you can do this:

```
import ast
liste = []  
for l in ex:
   for i in range(len(l)):
      l[i] = ast.literal_eval(l[i])
   liste.append(l)
```

Comment: Why would you use such a heavy module for a simple integer conversion?

Comment: It's a built-in module and it is generaly used for those kind of things

Comment: If you were to ask someone to pick between `int` and `ast` as to which function is used to parse a string representation of an integer, you'd almost always get `int` as the response.

Comment: of course ! It is not the subject but imagine that **ex** was a string and you want to convert it to a list of list of integers, that's the work of **ast**

Comment: You're right there. If the entire input was a string. ;-)

Comment: @JoshBagwel you are werlcome