# Why assign a new value to slice of a list can change the original list in python

Tags: python

```
# sample 1
a = [1,2,3]
a[:] = [4,5,6]
print(a)
>>> [4,5,6]
# sample 2
a = [1,2,3]
a[:].append(4)
print(a)
>>> [1,2,3]
```

Why could this happen?
The address of a and a[:] is different, why they are connected? What is the difference between these 2 solutions?

Comment: I'm not getting the same output as you (Python 3.6.2) - the final print returns `[4, 5, 6]` (which is expected)

Comment: The short answer is that slice assignment is a specific operation that is semantically different from simply taking a slice, much like `+=` is semantically a different operation than `= ... + ...`. As to **why** it's designed that way: you'll probably need to ask GvR.

Comment: @TerryA just two code samples...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`a[:]` hasn't the same meaning/works different ways in both examples

In the first example:

```
a[:] = [4,5,6]
```

you're assigning to `a` using [slice assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10623302/how-assignment-works-with-python-list-slice). It changes the contents of `a`. That's one way to completely change a list without changing its reference.

In the second example:

```
a[:].append(4)
```

`a[:]` creates a shallow copy of the list, just like `list(a)` or `copy.copy(a)`, then the code appends `4` to this very copy of `a`, therefore, `a` isn't changed.

Comment: Thanks! But if I assign another var just like b = a.copy(), this is a shallow copy of a, then i make b = [4,5,6], but a is still [1,2,3]. Why could this happen?

Comment: `b = a.copy()` then `a` and `b` are different. use `b = a` if you want them same