Python List Slicing Mystery
Pray tell WTH is going on here:
my_favorite_desserts = ["cheesecake", "bugs"]

my_favorite_desserts.append("cookies")

print(f"i love {my_favorite_desserts}")
my_favorite_desserts[10:10] = "heeeeellllooooooooooooooo"
my_favorite_desserts.remove('bugs')
print(f"i love {my_favorite_desserts}")

Output:
i love ['cheesecake', 'bugs', 'cookies']

i love ['cheesecake', 'cookies', 'h', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'l', 'l', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o']


I get that assigning a slice reference is odd. So is using a slice like 10:10 since this evaluates to [].
So, somehow, Python appends to the list the RHS of the assignment - but, not really! It takes that string and converts it to a list of chars, and appends that!
I don't know much Python but this seems quite batty.

Probably just a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10623302/how-does-assignment-work-with-list-slices and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48022943/how-is-this-list-expanded-with-the-slicing-assignment +  knowing that strings are iterables

No mystery? Ok. Coming from statically-typed languages that value type safety, this is serious wild-west sh-t.

There is nothing inconsistent about slice-assignment with static typing or type safety, yes, python is dynamically typed, but that's not relevant here, this could exist in any kind of language. I think you believe that the str object is being "turned into a list" it isn't. str objects are iterables, they have a method with a signature def __iter__(self) -> Iterable[str] where the str objects are length-1 strings

If you're coming from C, you should be used to the idea that strings are arrays of characters.

Of course. Obviously that's only tangentially related to this behavior.
You do understand that this kind of thing would never occur in a statically-typed language, and why, right?

The difference between the append method and assignment to a slice is explained and documented here https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types.  It may seem batty to you but the behavior is documented, and there are use cases that motivate the two different behaviors.

@BenderRodriguez no, I don't understand that at all. Why do you believe this sort of method couldn't exist in a statically typed language?

Note that for a list x, x[0:0] = 5 is a syntax error, because assignment to a slice requires an iterable.  However, x.append(5) is of course perfectly acceptable.  It's the same issue - assignment to a slice is simply NOT equivalent to append.

On second glance, I was missing something – the type of the parameter to append is it Iterable. So yes we might see similar behavior in a statically-typed language. I was wrong. In other words there is no transformation of the collection type here, of course. It remains a collection of strings. What happened was that the parameter to append was interpreted as an Iterable, which it is. My bad!

If you're wondering what's going on here, overall: I'm teaching my 10yo son Python, using a kid's programming book. It doesn't talk about types at all (yet). So I missed that append() takes an Iterable (collection) rather than an element. He came up with this code, asked me what was going on, and darned if I knew. (I'm not a Python guy.)

append() does take an element (or rather makes the argument an element), of any type, doesn't need to be an iterable.

I see that now! extend() takes the Iterable. So, the arg for append can be an Iterable - and, thus, this DOES come down to lack of static typing, more or less. (There's no strongly-typed language in which strings are coerced into iterables/collections implicitly.)

If your trying to append it to a list do my_desserts.append("heeeeellllooooooooooooooo")
.append() is a list function to add at the end of a list 1 element
(I can't comment so this answer may be incorrect to your situation because your details of what you wanted were really low)

I don't think this answers the question. OP knows how to append to a list - their question is "why doesn't this other thing work," not "what should I do instead."

As you said yourself this answer should be a comment. Not having enough reputation to comment does not mean you should post comments as answers. It means you have to earn enough reputation to post comments first.
