# python variable change questions

Tags: python, dictionary

Could anyone help to explain, why the values in dictionary change when using 'append'.

```
dic1 = {1:[[1],[2]]}
for x in dic1.keys():
    for tt in dic1[x]:
        print tt
        tt = tt + [1]
        print tt
dic1
```

output:

```
[1]
[1, 1]
[2]
[2, 1]
Out[67]:
{1: [[1], [2]]}
```

---

However

```
dic1 = {1:[[1],[2]]}
for x in dic1.keys():
    for tt in dic1[x]:
        print tt
        tt.append("s")
        print tt
dic1
```

output - if use append instead of plus, dic1 changed

```
[1]
[1, 's']
[2]
[2, 's']
Out[68]:
{1: [[1, 's'], [2, 's']]}
```

Comment: Sounds like you could use a quick guide to the difference between variables and objects: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: Because it will create a new list when you do `tt = tt + [1]` because of which no value is changes but with append you update the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `tt` in `tt = tt + [1]` is a local name, not the one inside `dic1`. Thus you changed the valued of this local name, not the value inside the `dic1`.

If you want to modify the object itself like in your first solution, use `tt[:]`:

```
dic1 = {1:[[1],[2]]}
for x in dic1.keys():
    for tt in dic1[x]:
        print tt
        tt[:] = tt + [1]
        print tt
```

Comment: Thank you @liliscent.  another question,  "[:] is the array slice syntax for every element in the array."  still don't understand that why [:] helps to change the value inside dic1.

Comment: found the explanation from here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10623302/how-assignment-works-with-python-list-slice :)

Answer (score 0):

This happens because lists are mutable and `append` changes the object itself instead of creating a new one.

In the first case the `+` actually creates a new object, so the original `tt` in the dictionary is not altered.

However in the second case, `append` does modify the actual dictionary's `tt`

Answer (score 0):

Append treats the list as mutable, whereas addition does not.

```
list = [1,2,3]
print(id(list))
list.append(1)
print(id(list))
list = list + [1]
print(id(list))
```

In other words append does not create a new object in memory, it just modifys the object that's already there, whereas addition creates an entirely new object. In the context of the dictionary, this means the values within it are changed when using append.