# Questions about UserList __init__, ( [:], isinstance )

Tags: python, python-3.x, cpython

I wanted to extend the class list in python37 with some custom methods.
and ended up reading the [UserList cpython code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/ffef50f1f5907e5f0f175b12088d3e509011f126/Lib/collections/__init__.py#L1066-L1077). After reading it new questions arose with regards of `[:]` usage.

If I understand correctly the `[:]` makes a slice copy of the whole
`self.data`. But I am trying to see what is the point of using `[:]`
at the left side of the `=` operator.

Is there any difference between option one and two? Tried in the python
interpreter, and both seem to have the same effect, am I missing
something?

```
letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
# option (1)
letters[:] = []
# option (2)
letters = []
```

Now it comes my questions with regards to UserList code. I added comments with questions I have.

```
class UserList(_collections_abc.MutableSequence):
    def __init__(self, initlist=None):
        self.data = []
        if initlist is not None:
            if type(initlist) == type(self.data):
            # NOTE: Is this if statement doing the same?
            # if isinstance(initlist, list):
                self.data[:] = initlist
                # NOTE: wouldn't in this case self.data keep a reference to initlist
                # instead of a copy?
                # self.data[:] = initlist[:]  # could one replace that line with this one?
            elif isinstance(initlist, UserList):
                self.data[:] = initlist.data[:]
                # NOTE: would this line accomplish the same?
                # self.data = initlist.data[:]
            else:
                self.data = list(initlist)
    ...
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How assignment works with python list slice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10623302/how-assignment-works-with-python-list-slice)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They don't behave the same if you have *another* reference to `letters`.

Scenario 1: modifying `letters` in place.

```
>>> letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
>>> lst = letters
>>> letters[:] = []
>>> letters
>>> []
>>> lst
>>> []
```

Scenario 2, reassigning the name `letters` to an empty list.

```
>>> letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
>>> lst = letters
>>> letters = []
>>> letters
>>> []
>>> lst
>>> ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
```

Since [names are reassigned independently](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html), `lst` does not see any change.

If you had

```
self.data = initlist
```

mutations to `initlist` would affect `self.data` (since they are the same object in memory).

Answer (score 0):

When you specify a on the left side of the = operator, you are using Python's normal assignment, which changes the name a in the current context to point to the new value. This does not change the previous value to which a was pointing.

By specifying a[0:2] on the left side of the = operator, you are telling Python you want to use Slice Assignment. Slice Assignment is a special syntax for lists, where you can insert, delete, or replace contents from a list.
See: [How assignment works with python list slice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10623302/how-assignment-works-with-python-list-slice)

Maybe this helps you.