# Is it possible to alter a list outside of a function?

Tags: python, function

My professor assigned a project in which we perform a series of alterations to a list. We are provided with a main function such as:

```
CURRENT_LIST = [1,2,3,4,5]

def main():
    data = list(CURRENT_LIST)
    shiftRight(data)
    print("After shifting data", data)
```

Basically, we have to write functions that handle these functions that `main()` is calling. I understand how to write the functions. For example, shifting everything to the right would yield something like:

```
def shiftRight(data:list) -> (list):
     data = data[-1:] + data[:-1]
     return(data)
```

My question is: is it possible to do this without altering the `main()` function we were provided with? From my understanding, after calling `shiftRight()`, I would have to assign it to the list again. Something like:

```
   data = shiftRight(data)
```

But the main function we were provided with is not set up like that. I am wondering if I can reassign the `data` list without modifying the `main()` function. I would like to avoid using global variables as well, as I don't think that was my professor's intention.

Has he made a mistake in the `main()` we were provided with? Or is there truly a way to modify this list without using `global variables` and without modifying `main()`?

Comment: Consider the possibility of changing `data` in-place (though eg `data[1:] = data[:-1]` ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the **content** of the list, this will make an update to the original list that is pointer by the variable instead of creating a new one:

```
>>> l = list(range(10))
>>> l
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> def shiftRight(l):
...     l[:] = l[-1:] + l[:-1]
... 
>>> shiftRight(l)
>>> l
[9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Comment: Interesting, it works. My only question is: why? From my understanding, if you have a list, "somelist", then "somelist[:]" refers to a copy of that list. So, how is shiftRight(l) working? It looks to me like it's creating a copy of the list with alterations of the pointed list. I am curious about the backend of the solution, albeit it works. Thank you.

Comment: @127dot0dot0dot1, you have a thread explaining that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10623352/1695172, it is really interesting :)

Comment: Very interesting and well-articulated thread. Thank you for answering all my questions!

Answer (score 0):

The `main` function looks at `CURRENT_LIST`, makes a copy of it, and then calls that copy `data`. It then passes `data` to a function called `shiftRight`, which accepts a list and performs a right shift on that list. This function mutates the list in-place and returns `None` (which happens by default if you omit a `return` statement). Then `main` prints the result.

The `def shiftRight...` you have there should be placed outside the `main` function, right after the assignment of `CURRENT_LIST`. You will also need to tweak that `shiftRight` function to mutate the passed list rather than creating and returning a new one. Try the `pop` and `insert` list methods for this.