# adding a string to a single item of a list

Tags: python

I want to prepend the last item of my list `BinList` with a string `less than or equal to`. `BinList` is 10 items long.

I have prepended all the other items in my list with a string `less than` using this function I wrote:

```
def prepend(list, string):
    string += '{0}'
    list = [string.format(i) for i in list]
    return (list)
```

But I can't use this for a single item in a list.

I tried

```
lastbin = BinList[10]
string = 'less than or equal to '
FinalCell = string.format(lastbin)
```

But this just returns `less than or equal to`

and not the number of `BinList[10]` as well.

Comment: What is the length of BinList?

Comment: Doesn't there need to be `{}` in the format string? `string = 'less than or equal to {}'`

Comment: you are not using `format` correctly. `'less than or equal to {}'.format(lastbin[-1])`

Comment: You're probably not approaching this the right way. Why are you just appending/prepending a string like that to every element on the list? If this is going to be shown as some kind of output, just do it there. You typically don't want to store formatting info into a data structure

Comment: `BinList` is 10 items long

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to loop or anything just use slicing like your second example but simple assign in the same line. Also BinList[-1] will access the last elemnt in the list:

```
 BinList[-1] = 'less than or equal to {}'.format(BinList[-1])
```

You can even make prepend treat the last element in the list apart from the others:

```
BinList = [1, 2, 3]

def prepend(l, string, last):
    length = len(l)
    return [[last, string][i<length-1].format(s) for i, s in enumerate(l)]

print(prepend(BinList, 'equal to {}', 'less than or equal to {}'))
```

This returns:

```
['equal to 1', 'equal to 2', 'less than or equalto 3']
```

Comment: Won't this only work for the last element in `BinList`

Comment: OP said they wanted to append to the last element in the list.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Will change my answer too

Answer (score 1):

```py
def prepend(list, string, last_string):
    list[:-1] = [(string + str(i)) for i in list[:-1]]
    list[-1] = last_string + str(list[-1])
    return list

prepend([1, 2, 'tank'], 'less than ', 'less than or equal to ')
# ['less than 1', 'less than 2', 'less than or equal to tank']
```

- For above, `list[:-1] = [1, 2]` (exclude last item)
- Regarding `list[:-1] =`, see [list slicing vs assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10623302/how-assignment-works-with-python-list-slice)