# Why this parameter list doesn't change in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, variable-assignment

I created a function f which uses a 2-dimension list as parameter, but after this function the list does not change at all.
As the code below:

```
def f(t: [[int]]):
    for eachrow in t:
        eachrow = eachrow[1:]
        eachrow.append(0)

A = [[2, 10, 0], [3, 1, 2], [3, 2, 1]]

f(A)

print(A)  # -> [[2, 10, 0], [3, 1, 2], [3, 2, 1]]
```

Comment: You're only updating the loop variable, not the input parameter

Comment: @cricket_007 `eachrow` is initially an item in `t`, but the slicing overwrites it. I posted an answer about this.

Comment: BTW welcome to Stack Overflow ClassicalPi! Check out the [tour].

Comment: Note, this is not correctly type annotated: `t: [[int]]` should be `t: typing.List[typing.List[int]]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assigning to `eachrow` in `eachrow = eachrow[1:]` overwrites it. So to remove the first element, you could use `del` instead, or `row.pop` or [slice assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10623302/4518341).

```
def f(t):
    for row in t:
        del row[0]  # OR row.pop(0) OR row[:] = row[1:]
        row.append(0)

A = [[2, 10, 0], [3, 1, 2], [3, 2, 1]]
f(A)
print(A)  # -> [[10, 0, 0], [1, 2, 0], [2, 1, 0]]
```

Comment: Technically, it's not that the slice is making a copy, it's that the assignment is happening to a local variable. You would get the same result if the loop body was instead `eachrow = 0`.

Comment: @wmorrell You're right! But why does assigning to a slice work? Is it cause it assigns to the "interior" of the list instead of the name?

Comment: @wjandrea this is slice-assignment notation: `row[:] = row[1:]`, it isn't the same as "assigning to a slice", that is, it doesn't create a slice (which is just a new list) and assign to that new one, rather, it simply modifies to the original

Comment: @wmorrell to be clear, `eachrow[1:]` on the right hand side **does** create a slice, i.e. a whole new `list` object

Comment: Saying a whole new `list` object is a bit misleading. A slice creates a new `slice`, which references the original `list` items. The items themselves are not copied, which is what most people would expect when saying "new `list` object". In other words, `a = row[:]` is different from `a = list(row)`.

Answer (score -1):

If you print out the results of your changes to `eachrow`, you'll see that you ARE updating the `eachrow` variable, but that doesn't affet the original `t` variable.

```
def f(t):
    for eachrow in t:
        eachrow = eachrow[1:]
        eachrow.append(0)
        print(eachrow)
```

```
>>> f(A)
[10, 0, 0]
[1, 2, 0]
[2, 1, 0]
```

If you want to affect the array itself, you should modify the array like so:

```
def f(t):
    for row_number in range(len(t)):
        t[row_number] = t[row_number][1:]
        t[row_number].append(0)
```

Comment: It's not the iterating over `t` that's the problem, it's the slicing. I posted an answer about this. BTW a list is an iterable, not an iterator since it doesn't get exhausted; and I don't think Python has pointers - a Python name is more like a reference IIRC. But indexing `t` is a perfectly fine way to solve the problem.

Comment: " the iterator over the elements of that array are COPIES of the element of that list," absolutely incorrect. They are not copies. Put any mutable variable in a list, say, another list: `data = [[], []]` then do `for x in data: x.append(0)` then print `data` and you'll see that the lists inside the outer list have each been modified.

Comment: Noted! Fixed in the answer.

Comment: Thank you to both of you @wjandrea and juanpa for catching this.

Comment: @j6m8 Whoops, I was wrong actually, it's not the slicing, it's the assignment. wmorrel corrected me and I updated my answer.

Comment: Fair point! I'll update in mine to reflect the same information for the sake of accuracy.