# I’m trying to flip every second sub list in a list of lists. Does any one have suggestions?

Tags: python-3.x

`My_list= [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]` ———-> `[[1,2,3],[6,5,4],[7,8,9]]`

I tried using this with out success :

```
for i my_list:
    if my_list.index(i) != 0:
        i = i[::-1]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option (in addition to @DeepSpace answer) is using Python's slicing notation ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation)) and assigning to slice ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10623302/how-assignment-works-with-python-list-slice)):

In this example, we create slice starting from index 1 and step 2 and assign reverse sublist to it:

```
my_list = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]

my_list[1::2] = (v[::-1] for v in my_list[1::2])

print(my_list)
```

Prints:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [6, 5, 4], [7, 8, 9]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Since Python `for` loops create local variables, you have to index into the outer list indexes and use `% 2 == 1` to detect sublists with odd indexes.

```
my_list = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]

for index, sublist in enumerate(my_list):
    if index % 2 == 1:
        my_list[index] = sublist[::-1]

print(my_list)
```

Outputs

```
[[1, 2, 3], [6, 5, 4], [7, 8, 9], [12, 11, 10]]
```