# Python3 Understanding list assignment (shallow/deep copy or ref)

Tags: python-3.x, list

I would like to know what the difference is between the last two list assignments below

```
List1 = [0x1,0x2,0x3,0x4]
print('{}, 0x{:X}'.format(List1, id(List1)))
List1 = List1[1:]
print('{}, 0x{:X}'.format(List1, id(List1)))
List1[:] = List1[1:]
print('{}, 0x{:X}'.format(List1, id(List1)))
```

The print out when I execute this is

```
[1, 2, 3, 4], 0x2DBA09E8C88
[2, 3, 4], 0x2DBA1342B48
[3, 4], 0x2DBA1342B48
```

After I have created the list.

I make what I believe is a shallow copy.

But what does the last assignment do ? It keeps its address so there is not created a new object.

I cant seem to find en explanation on this on this in the net, what should I look for

Regards

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How assignment works with Python list slice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10623302/how-assignment-works-with-python-list-slice) Some more helpful links: [Mutable Sequence Types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types), [Assignment statements](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements)

Comment: The answer did help me.