# Since slice does shallow copies why can it be used update the original mutable collection?

Tags: python, slice, shallow-copy

I know that slice operator does a shallow copy.

But when I used the slice operator on a list of integers and mutate the slice then the mutation was reflected in the original list. Since integers are immutable, the result confused me.

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
print("Before slicing...")
print(x)
print("Slicing...")
x[1::2]=[0]*len(x[1::2])
print("After slicing...")
print(x)
x[2:2]=[1]
print(x)
```

The output was

```
Before slicing...
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
Slicing...
After slicing...
[1, 0, 3, 0, 5, 0, 7, 0, 9, 0]
[1, 0, 1, 3, 0, 5, 0, 7, 0, 9, 0]
```

Since `x[1::2]` and `x[2:2]` does a shallow copy why does a change to it reflected in the original list?

Comment: Because you explicitly put that slice back into the original list.

Comment: @jonrsharpe What does that mean I didn't assign it to original list?

Comment: Yes you did, that's what the slice notation on the left hand side of the = means. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10623302/how-assignment-works-with-python-list-slice

Comment: @jonrsharpe So when used on the left hand side of the `=` operator, does slice operator behaves as an indexing for the original list?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thank you very much that post solved it.