# Splitting string to individual characters using slicing

Tags: python, string, split

I'm confused how the following python code works to split a string to individual characters using `b[:0] = a`. Shouldn't it be just `b = ['abc']`?

```
a='abc'
b=[]
b[:0]=a
print(b)
```

output:

```
b=[a,b,c]
```

Comment: [Multiple explanations here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10623302/how-assignment-works-with-python-list-slice) in particular answer by Casey Kuball.

Comment: @aderchox The question is more about why the piece of code behaves so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the [list constructor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list) can be used to split any iterables, such as strings.

You do not even need `[:0]`,

```py
list(a) # ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

or,

```py
b = []
b[:] = a # ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [Python Doc](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements) whenever left side of assignment statement is slicing, python do `__setitem__` so in this case it put right side items in the beginning of slicing. take a look at this example:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4]
>>> b = [5,6,7,8]
>>> b[3:5] = a
>>> print(b)
[5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's two things at play here

When you do

```py
b[:0] = <something>
```

The something is inserted to the beginning of the list (This is appending to a list slice)

If you did

```py
b[1:3] = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Then the items at index `1` and `2` are replaced by the items on the right

Try the following:

```py
b = []
b[:0] = [1, 2, 3]
```

You will notice the items on the right inserted to the beginning of the list

Now when you do

```py
b[:0] = "abc"
```

Since the items on the right hand side have to be a sequence, the string gets unpacked to `['a', 'b', 'c']` and then these are inserted to the beginning of the list