# Editing each element within the lists within the values of a dictionary (Python)

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary, list-comprehension

Here's my attempt at grabbing the dictionary:

```
pairs = {'EMOTIONS': ['happy', 'angry', 'sad', 'calm'], 'TRAITS': ['impatient', 'persistent', 'meek']}
```

And turning it into a dictionary whose values are written as a phrase, so that:

```
pairs = {'EMOTIONS': ['I am happy', 'I am angry', 'I am sad', 'I am calm'], 'TRAITS': ['I am impatient', 'I am persistent', 'I am stubborn']}
```

Here's the code so far:

```
pairs = {'EMOTIONS': ['happy', 'angry', 'sad', 'calm'], 'TRAITS': ['impatient', 'persistent', 'meek']}
I_am = 'I am '

for title, words in pairs.items():
    words = [I_am+word for word in words]
```

I'm obviously doing something wrong because when I request **print(pairs)**, it returns the exact same dictionary I began with. What do I change to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a new dictionary and writing to that in the for loop:

```
modpairs = {}
for title, words in pairs.items():
    words = [I_am+word for word in words]
    modpairs[title] = words
print(modpairs)
```

Comment: You could modify the values in-place in `pairs` but modifying a dictionary while iterating over its items is not a good general practice.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to mutate the list, not just rebind the loop variable:

```
for words in pairs.values():
    words[:] = [I_am + word for word in words]
    # or, if you want to be fancy
    words[:] = map(I_am.__add__, words)
```

This uses [slice assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10623302/how-assignment-works-with-python-list-slice) to change the `list` object.

Answer (score 0):

Using single for loop.

```
    pairs = {'EMOTIONS': ['happy', 'angry', 'sad', 'calm'], 'TRAITS': ['impatient', 'persistent', 'meek']}
    dic = {}
    for x,y in pairs.items():dic[x]=list(map(lambda x:'I am '+x,y))
    print(dic)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you say

```
    words = [I_am+word for word in words]
```

you create a new list with the prefix you are looking for, and assign that list to the local variable `words`, but you do not change the dict's value in any way. To achieve that, this should work:

```
new_pairs = {key: [I_am + adjective for adjective in pairs[key]] for key in pairs}
```