# can't understand how assigning characters in string to list through list slicing works in following piece of code

Tags: python, string, list, slice

I can't understand how string is assigned to the list

```py
def convert(string): 
    list1 = []
    list1[:0] = string 
    return list1 

# Driver code 
str1 = "ABCD"
print(convert(str1))
```

Comment: That's a really silly way of doing `list(string)`

Comment: In any case, slice-assignment essentially "extends" into the slice range, overwriting anything inside that slice range, but not anything beyond it. The example you showed is needlessly confusing and undiomatic. So consider, `data = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]; data[1:3] = "ABCDEFG"`

Comment: The question is not about the best practice of doing this action. it is about how it works

Comment: Note that you shouldn't so much worry how this works, rather why someone would use such a convoluted code. Yes, it makes sense if one is familiar with Python. No, there is no reason to actually do it that way.

Comment: @MehrdadPedramfar yes, I understand that but it **really** should be pointed out that the code as written is silly and needlessly confusing

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I believe that OP see's this code here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-convert-string-list/

Comment: So, if you do slice assignment, `data[n:n]` it inserts/extends the sequence at `n` without overwriting anythingin the sequence.  So `list1[:0]` is essentially equivalent to `list1[0:0]` so it just inserts everything at the beginning, since the list is empty anyway

Comment: @MehrdadPedramfar ok, it is silly code that should never be written like that and it would be excoriated in any sane code review at any place with a modicum of standards. But thanks for finding that, it's disappointing, Geeks for Geeks is usually an OK source.

Comment: I agree. @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: What parts of this *do* you understand? Are you aware of [slice assignment](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How assignment works with Python list slice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10623302/how-assignment-works-with-python-list-slice)

Answer (score 2):

As it looks its a way of converting a string to a list, you can do it like

```
list(string)
```

but this is also quite interesting as , it takes whatever is the input the append it in the start of the list,
[from python docs list insertion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSWOd.png)

list1[0:0] inserts the iterable to before the first element of the list, if you slice the list to go up to zero elemen it gives you an empty list