# Python list reversing function confusion

Tags: python

```
def f(x):
    x = x[::-1]
list = [1,2,3]
f(list)
print(list)

OUTPUT: [1,2,3]
```

Can someone explain why the list didn't reverse? In the next example it reverses, but why? I can't really understand this behavior.

```
def f(x):
    x[:] = x[::-1]
list = [1,2,3]
f(list)
print(list)

OUTPUT: [3,2,1]
```

Comment: Because `x = x[::-1]` doesn't mutate the list in-place. It creates a *new list* and assigns it to the local variable `x`. That list is discarded when the function terminates. On the other hand, `x[:] = whatever` *does* mutate the list. Indeed, `x[:] = x[::-1]` actually creates a new list, and that new list is used to mutate the original list. You should probably read https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: In any case, you should simply use the built-in method `.reverse()` to reverse a list in-place

Comment: Very good explanatoin @juanpa.arrivillaga!

Comment: Im confused because x[:] creates a new list, but how is that new list used to mutate the original one?  @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: @user737163 because `x[:] = whavtever` mutates a list, it is slice-assignment. It is essentially a call to `x.__setitem__(slice(None), whatever)`

Comment: @user737163 see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10623302/how-assignment-works-with-python-list-slice basically, the expression `x[:]` is a distinct thing from the statement `x[:] = y`. The former is equivalent to `x.__getitem__(slice(None))` and the latter is equivalent to `x.__setitem__(slice(None), y)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the juanpa.arrivillaga's comment,

> Because `x = x[::-1]` doesn't mutate the list in-place. It creates a new list and assigns it to the local variable `x`. That list is discarded when the function terminates. On the other hand, `x[:] = whatever` does mutate the list. Indeed, `x[:] = x[::-1]` actually creates a new list, and that new list is used to mutate the original list

And you could use the built-n method `.reverse()` to reverse a list

```
mylist = [1,2,3]
mylist.reverse()
print(mylist)
```

Or you could use reversed:

```
mylist = [1,2,3]
mylist = reversed(mylist)
print(list(mylist))
```

And try to avoid using built-in function name `list` in variable names.

Comment: "should" might not be the correct word. you can very well use `[::-1]` or `reverse` deepening upon use case.

Comment: Ah, sorry. changed to could

Comment: `list(reversed(mylist))` might be the only bad use case for `reversed(mylist)` :-P

Comment: Im confused because x[:] creates a new list, but how is that new list used to mutate the original one?