# Explanation of iterable object assignment in specific range by list slicing (ex, arr[1:3] = 'ABCD')

Tags: python, slice, variable-assignment

```
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
arr[1:3] = 'ABCD'
arr
[1, 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 4, 5]
```

Exactually, this code is useless. I don't think anyone uses python lists like this. But i wanna know about the result just because of curiosity.

I can know something intuitively seeing result.

> old `arr[1:3]` (`2, 3`) is gone and replaced by string `'ABCD'` sequentially.

But just fact about results, I can't understand how it works.

Can I get some hint or docs for understand this result?

Comment: `foo[x:y] = z` is effectively equivalent to `foo[:x] + list(z) + foo[y:]`, except the elements of `list(z)` are inserted in-place, instead of building a new list.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How assignment works with Python list slice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10623302/how-assignment-works-with-python-list-slice) Note that [this answer](/a/10623383/4518341) is much more thorough than the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slice assignment takes an ***iterable*** on the right-hand. Many things can be iterables, an array or list, for example `[8, 9]`:

```
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
arr[1:3] = [8, 9]
arr
[1, 8, 9, 4, 5]
```

A string is an iterable of characters, as you can see in this example

```
for x in 'ABCD':
    print(x)
A
B
C
D
```

which is why get the result you got. So if what you want is to replace the `arr[1:3]` slice with a single array element that's a string, you need to give it an iterable that yields that element:

```
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
arr[1:3] = ['ABCD']
arr
[1, 'ABCD', 4, 5]
```

Note the brackets around the string in the slice assignment statement.