# Understanding (not so) basic numpy indexing example

Tags: python, numpy

I am reading numpy's documentation and in the section "basic indexing" there is an example that I am struggling to understand.

Documentation link: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#basics-indexing

The code:

```
x = np.arange(0, 50, 10)
array([ 0, 10, 20, 30, 40])
x[np.array([1, 1, 3, 1])] += 1
```

Returns:

```
array([ 0, 11, 20, 31, 40])
```

I am scratching my head because I imagined that the left-hand side created a new array, not a view. And indeed it does:

```
np.shares_memory(x, x[np.array([1, 1, 3, 1])])
```

Returns:

```
False
```

Thus, I imagined that iadd (`+=`) was being called on a new array, but that is not the case because  *somehow* this operation is modifying the original array.

If I correctly understood the [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing), `x[np.array([1, 1, 3, 1])]` triggers a "advanced indexing", which "always returns a copy of the data".

**The "question": can someone help me understand that is going on here? A step-by-step description of what is going on would be appreciated.**

edit: more specifically, what I imagined would happen:

1. create a temporary new array with `[10, 10, 30, 10]`
2. try assign `[10, 10, 30, 10] + 1` to this new array
3. broadcast `1` to allow the summation
4. assign the result of the sum, `[11, 11, 31, 11]`, to the temporary array

Since there is no reference to this temporary array I imagined this would effectively be a noop.

Comment: How would you expect 'x[0]+=1' to behave? Copy scalar from original array?

Comment: My expectation is that "scalar indexing" returns a reference/view and "sequence of integers indexing" returns a copy. Thus, I expect x[0] += 1 to increment the first element.

Comment: the np.array in line 3 only select index 1 and 3 so only these elements are incremented.

Comment: @Trauer " I imagined that the left-hand side created a new array, not a view." **it doesn't create anything**. it is part of an item-assignment statement.

Comment: This should probably be closed as a duplicate for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10623302/how-does-assignment-work-with-list-slices

Comment: All your 4 steps occur on the RHS.  The confusion is over what happens when `[11,11,31,11]` is assigned to `x[np.array([1, 1, 3, 1])]`.  `x` itself is modified, with values from the temporary array.

Answer (score 1):

It's not made entirely clear but left-of-assignment syntax `x[...] = ...` does something different (`x.__setitem__`) from right-of-assignment/normal expression syntax `x[...]` (`x.__getitem__`). Generally, `__setitem__` modifies specified elements in the original object, while `__getitem__` returns a new object accessing the specified elements.

It's not just NumPy arrays. Think of a basic Python list. `x[0]` extracts an element, but `x[0] = 5` changes the list.

Smaller nitpick, you're not talking about basic slicing, `x[np.array([1, 1, 3, 1])]` is *advanced indexing*. Basic slicing makes a view that shares data with the original, advanced indexing copies data. In both cases they make a new NumPy array.

Comment: Indeed. That was a typo! The title of the question was correct but the first paragraph incorrect. I will fix it.

Comment: Yet list[slice] =5,  which is the closest thing to a numpy integer sequence indexing, does not.

Comment: But here is the thing... "advanced indexing" should "always return a copy": https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing

Comment: You're not returning something when `x[...]` is an l-value though are you, you're assigning to it? It would seem that the reference you posted only applies to r-values? I would be interested in the mechanism myself.

Comment: @Trauer 1) you can't do `list[slice] = 5` because lists didn't implement broadcasting. To be clear, `x[...] = ...` is implemented by the `__setitem__` method while `x[...]` is implemented by `__getitem__`. It's up to those methods to implement features. 2) The NumPy docs is exactly what I was talking about when I said "it's not made entirely clear". It talks about the `__getitem__` part, not so much the `__setitem__` part.

Comment: @Trauer try `list[slice] = some_iterable_with_len_slice_elements`, it works just like with numpy.ndarrays

Comment: The question was about '+=' operator, not '='

Answer (score 1):

The talk about `view` versus `copy` applies to the `__getitem__` indexing; not to the `__setitem__` (or `__iadd__`).   You are using `+=` with a duplicate index, which complicates the whole process.

```
In [44]: x = np.arange(0, 50, 10)
In [45]: x
Out[45]: array([ 0, 10, 20, 30, 40])
```

This does make a copy, a new array with values taken from the `x`:

```
In [46]: x[np.array([1, 1, 3, 1])]
Out[46]: array([10, 10, 30, 10])
```

But this assigns values to elements of `x`, specifically to 2 elements, indexed with 1 and 3:

```
In [47]: x[np.array([1, 1, 3, 1])] += 1
In [48]: x
Out[48]: array([ 0, 11, 20, 31, 40])   # only 10 and 30 have incremented
```

If instead we do the += iteratively, the `10` is incremented 3 times:

```
In [49]: x = np.arange(0, 50, 10)
In [50]: for i in [1, 1, 3, 1]: x[i] += 1
In [51]: x
Out[51]: array([ 0, 13, 20, 31, 40])
```

Or we can use `np.add.at`:

```
In [57]: x = np.arange(0, 50, 10)
In [58]: np.add.at(x, np.array([1,1,3,1]),1)
In [59]: x
Out[59]: array([ 0, 13, 20, 31, 40])
```

Its documentation talks about `+=` using buffering, which explains why `10` only becomes `11`.

Another example, this time a simple assignment

```
In [60]: x = np.arange(0, 50, 10)
In [61]: x[np.array([1, 1, 3, 1])] = [100,101,102,103]
In [62]: x
Out[62]: array([  0, 103,  20, 102,  40])    # only 103 remains
```

In fact the assignment explains the += case

```
In [63]: x = np.arange(0, 50, 10)
In [64]: x[np.array([1, 1, 3, 1])]+1
Out[64]: array([11, 11, 31, 11])
In [65]: x[np.array([1, 1, 3, 1])] = _  
In [66]: x
Out[66]: array([ 0, 11, 20, 31, 40])
```

31 is assigned to `x[3]` and 11 to `x[1]`