# How do I use a loop statement to change specific values in a dictionary given an if statement?

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

If I have a dictionary with each key having a list of values for example:

```
my_dict={'key1':[1, 6, 7, -9], 'key2':[2, 5, 10, -5,], 'key3':[-8, 1, -2, 6]}
```

And I want to create a loop statement to go through each value within the lists and change the value within my dictionary to 0 for each negative value. I can create a loop statement to go through each value and check if the value is negative but I can't figure out how to amend the dictionary directly:

```
for keys, values in my_dict.items():
    for value in values:
        if value < 0:
            value=0
```

How to I alter that last line (or do I have to change more lines) to be able to amend my dictionary directly to replace the negative values with 0?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to iterate over the [`.items`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items) of the dictionary and override each value directly using [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) to keep track of the indices:

```
my_dict={'key1':[1, 6, 7, -9], 'key2':[2, 5, 10, -5,], 'key3':[-8, 1, -2, 6]}

for key, value in my_dict.items():
    for i, val in enumerate(value):
        value[i] = 0 if val < 0 else val

print(my_dict)
```

**Output**

```
{'key1': [1, 6, 7, 0], 'key2': [2, 5, 10, 0], 'key3': [0, 1, 0, 6]}
```

Alternative using the [slicing](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/brackets/slicing.html) operator and a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
for key, value in my_dict.items():
    value[:] = [0 if val < 0 else val for val in value]
```

Some other useful resources:

- [Looping Techniques](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#looping-techniques), discusses pythonic approaches to looping
- [Python names and values](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html) for understanding how *variables* work in Python
- [Slice assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10623302/how-does-assignment-work-with-list-slices) some light on how the second approach works

Comment: Thank you very much it has solved my issue and thank you for the resource on looping techniques!

Answer (score 0):

Using max in a nested comprehension:

```
my_dict = {k: [max(0, v) for v in vals] for k, vals in my_dict.items()}
```