# Why I'm getting this kind of output?

Tags: python, list, output, character, slice

I run this code on my desktop and and I enter `watermelon`
and code run ok but it split watermelon letter by letter

```
fruits = ['apple','pine','grape','mango','orange']
fruits[1:3] = input('Enter a fruit:')
print(fruits)
```

Output:

```
Enter a fruit: watermelon 
['apple','w','a','t','e','r','m','e','l','o','n','mango',orange']
```

Expected output:

```
['apple','watermelon','mango','orange']
```

Comment: What are you expecting instead?

Comment: When you do slice assignment, the source must be a sequence. A string is a sequence of characters.

Comment: @Barmar `['apple','watermelon','mango','orange']` is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're doing slice assignment, the source will be treated as a sequence. The slice `[1:3]` will be replaced by each element of the source sequence separately.

When a string is used as a sequence, each character is a separate element, so it gets split up and inserted into the list.

If you want to replace the slice with the whole string, wrap it in a list.

```
fruits[1:3] = [input('Enter a fruit:')]
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for taking your time:)

Comment: Sorry for bothering you. But, can you tell me why fruit[1:1] adds "watermelon" without removing other elements?

Comment: Because a slice doesn't include the end index. So the slice `[1:1]` is a zero-length slice, and nothing is removed.

Comment: Thanks again. But, I forgot to ask the actual thing . fruits[0:0] is added between fruits[0] and fruits[1]. Likewise, fruits[1:1] is fruits[1] and fruits[2]. I would like to know how this is happening?

Comment: When you assign to a slice, it deletes the original slice and then inserts the source list in its place. If the original slice is empty, it just inserts.

Comment: The insertion moves the following elements up to make room.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10623302/how-does-assignment-work-with-list-slices

Answer (score 3):

As the comments state, when executing fruits[1:3], you're creating a slice assignment which slices the word which was input and stores it in the 1 and 2 indexes (3 is excluded).

If you were just trying to add another fruit to the array of fruits,

```
fruits = ['apple','pine','grape','mango','orange']
fruit = input('Enter a fruit: ')
fruits.append(fruit)
print(fruits)
```

Alternatively, if you really wanted to replace the 2nd and 3rd places, you can do this,

```
fruits = ['apple','pine','grape','mango','orange']
fruits[1:3] = [input('Enter a fruit: ')]
print(fruits)
```

Which will produce,
`['apple', 'watermelon', 'mango', 'orange']`

Answer (score 1):

Following on what Barmar commented, try this code.

```
fruits = ['apple','pine','grape','mango','orange']
fruits[1:3] = [input('Enter a fruit:')]
print(fruits)
```

It will effectively replace second and third element in array (what I assume you wanted to achieve)

Answer (score -1):

Convert your input to a list explicitly and then assign to your original list.