# Python lists with 0 slice set to string

Tags: python, list

I'm struggling to make sense of the following for a python list:

```
L = []
L[0:] = 'string'       # equivalently L[:] = 'string'
```

and here L = ['s','t','r','i', 'n', 'g']

why does python do this? I know this is the expected behaviour of running

list('string')

but I'm not sure how to explain this behaviour.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does assignment work with list slices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10623302/how-does-assignment-work-with-list-slices)

Comment: It is because you are passing only one element and since you said you want to slice the string with `L[0:]` it is doing that, if there was more than just one element that you want to add it wouldn't do that. To set the string as the first element you can simply use `L.append('string')`.

Comment: @buran I don't think this answers my question - I'm specifically asking about the behavior when assigning a string to the whole slice L[:].

Comment: @BokiX `L='string'` convers L into a string, i'm asking about the behavior of the line `L[:] = 'string' `

Comment: Strings are kind of an odd duck in Python.  They are simultaneously a single object and an iterable.

Comment: @WeakLearner I meant `L.append('string')` sorry. Read my explanation above and see if it answers you.

Comment: @BokiX I appreciate the comment and I understand how to set the first element of L to be a specified string, but here I am trying to understand what is going on with the line `L[:] = 'string'` as opposed to asking how one should ideally do something in python

Comment: @MarkRansom could you say more about this? since strings are iterable then why exactly does the right hand side of `line L[:] = 'string' ` get interpreted as `L[:] = ['s', 't','r','i','n','g']` ??

Comment: If I knew the exact mechanics behind it I'd leave an answer instead of a comment.

Comment: Check https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements It explains the logic/mechanics.

Answer (score 0):

by making the left-hand-side `L[:]`, you force the right-hand side to be an iterable (if you try, for example L[:] = 1, it will result in a `TypeError`). Therefore, `L[:] = some_iterable_thing` translates as `iterate over some_iterable_thing and assign it to elements of the L list`.
Examples:

```
L[:] = 1,2,3 ==> [1,2,3]
L[:] = (1,2,3) ==> [1,2,3]
L[:] = 'string' ==> ['s','t','r','i','n','g']
L[:] = 1 ==> TypeError
L[:] = None ==> TypeError
```

Comment: So the workaround for the problem would be `L[:] = ['string']`?

Comment: why does making the left hand side `L[:]` force the right hand side to be an iterable ?

Comment: @WeakLearner A slice is a sequence of elements in the target list, so you need a sequence of values to assign to each element.

Comment: @MarkRansom to add an element to the list L, just L.append('string')

Comment: The question isn't about appending to the list, it's about replacing the contents of the list.  We should probably assume that the slice being the entire list was just a simplification for the purposes of asking the question.