# converting txt file into json using python?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, logfile

I have a log file that has the format as follows:

```
Nov 28 06:26:45 server-01 dhcpd: DHCPDISCOVER from cc:d3:e2:7a:af:40 via 10.39.192.1 
Nov 28 06:26:45 server-01 dhcpd: DHCPOFFER on 10.39.255.253 to cc:d3:e2:7a:af:40 via 10.39.192.1
```

The next step is to convert the text data into a JSON using Python. So far, I have the python script.
Now, the JSON file is created in the following format:

```py
# Python program to convert text
# file to JSON

import json

# the file to be converted
filename = 'Logs.txt'

# resultant dictionary
dict1 = {}

# fields in the sample file
fields =['timestamp', 'Server', 'Service', 'Message']

with open(filename) as fh:
    # count variable for employee id creation
    l = 1

    for line in fh:
        # reading line by line from the text file
        description = list( line.strip().split(None, 4))

        # for output see below
        print(description)

        # for automatic creation of id for each employee
        sno ='emp'+str(l)

        # loop variable
        i = 0
        # intermediate dictionary
        dict2 = {}
        while i<len(fields):

                # creating dictionary for each employee
                dict2[fields[i]]= description[i]
                i = i + 1

        # appending the record of each employee to
        # the main dictionary
        dict1[sno]= dict2
        l = l + 1

# creating json file
out_file = open("test5.json", "w")
json.dump(dict1, out_file, indent = 4)
out_file.close()
```

which gives the following output:

```
{
 "emp1": { "timestamp": "Nov", "Server": "28", "Service": "06:26:45", "Message": "server-01" },
 "emp2": { "timestamp": "Nov", "Server": "28", "Service": "06:26:45", "Message": "server-01" }
}
```

But I need an ouput like:

```
{
"timestamp":"Nov 28 06:26:26", 
"Server":"server-01", 
"Service":"dhcpd",
"Message":"DHCPOFFER on 10.45.45.31 to cc:d3:e2:7a:b9:6b via 10.45.0.1",
}
```

I don't know why it's not printing the whole data. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: What is the output which you are getting?

Comment: Here is my output:       "emp1": {
        "timestamp": "Nov",
        "Server": "28",
        "Service": "06:26:45",
        "Message": "server-01"
    },
    "emp2": {
        "timestamp": "Nov",
        "Server": "28",
        "Service": "06:26:45",
        "Message": "server-01"
    },

Comment: Could you please put a log sample as text and not as image, so we can copy paste?

Comment: Here is my log file: Nov 28 06:26:45 server-01 dhcpd: DHCPDISCOVER from cc:d3:e2:7a:af:40 via 10.39.192.1
Nov 28 06:26:45 server-01 dhcpd: DHCPOFFER on 10.39.255.253 to cc:d3:e2:7a:af:40 via 10.39.192.1

Comment: @Abhiyantraka as you can see, comments don't format code very well, so you should [edit] your question to add large blocks of code, as I just did.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you did `.split(None, 4)`, which allows only 4 splits on the input string. Since the date contains spaces too, the result of this will be (e.g. for the first line of your input):

```
['Nov',         # timestamp
 '28',          # Server
 '06:26:45',    # Service
 'server-01',   # Message
 'dhcpd: DHCPDISCOVER from cc:d3:e2:7a:af:40 via 10.39.192.1']
```

<sup>You even printed this, so I'm surprised you didn't notice something is wrong.</sup>

Now, the first element of the list is assigned to the key `'timestamp'`, the second element to the key `'Server'`, and so on. This is how you get a dict that looks like:

```
{ "timestamp": "Nov", "Server": "28", "Service": "06:26:45", "Message": "server-01" }
```

Instead, you want to split a maximum of *five* times. The first three elements of the resultant split are the timestamp.

```
# Don't need that extra list(), since .split() already returns a list
description = line.strip().split(None, 5) 

# Join the first three elements,
joined_timestamp = " ".join(description[:3])

# and replace them in the list
# Setting a slice of a list: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/10623302/843953
description[:3] = [joined_timestamp]
```

Then, your `description` looks like this:

```
['Nov 28 06:26:45',
 'server-01',
 'dhcpd:',
 'DHCPDISCOVER from cc:d3:e2:7a:af:40 via 10.39.192.1']
```

and the elements `fields` now correspond to the values in `description`.

Note that you could replace that entire `while i < len(fields)...` loop with simply `dict2 = dict(zip(fields, description))`

P.S.: You might want to clean up other elements of `description`, such as `description[2] = description[2].rstrip(":")` to remove the trailing colon in `'dhcpd:'`