# Why slicing of [:0] does not return an error?

Tags: python, slice

Why slicing of [:0] does not return an error?

- **Exercise: CHANGE the x list, to include the y list in the beginning, and the x list after it.
  Do NOT use the "+" operator, nor methods or functions.**

Staff Answer:

```
y = [1, 2, 3]
x = [4, 5, 6]
x[:0] = y
print(x)
```

Result: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

The question is, why isn't x[:0] producing an error?
What space is there before x[0]?

| Index |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 OR -1 | 1 | 2 etc... |

I mean, where does it fit?!
Is there space BEFORE the first index?!

Comment: Perhaps duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10623302/how-does-assignment-work-with-list-slices

Comment: @AndrejKesely A nice commneter explains how to do slicing, including a[0:0],but he doesn't explain WHY it works. So, no. It's not a duplicate. but thanks!

Comment: You can study the Python source code: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/1e68c4b87633b17da1b602b86f5d23bbe106398f/Objects/listobject.c#L895 The destination list is resized and new items from source list are getting copied to this new place.

Answer (score 1):

`x[:0]` is equivalent to `x[0:0]`, both of them are a slice of `x` starting from index `0` up to (not including) `0`. This effectively denotes a segment of the list where no elements are present, hence it results in an empty slice. Therefore, when you assign a list `y` to this slice, as in `x[:0] = y` or equivalently `x[0:0] = y`, you arere not replacing any elements in `x` because the slice is empty.

Instead, you're inserting all elements of `y` at the beginning of the list.

Comment: I mean yeah, this part I got from the Staff's explanation. thanks.
But when Python inserts list y into x[0:0], at what index does python put it in? at what space? Is there space before the [0] index, that [0:0] CAN denote? I mean, it works, but how?

Comment: There is no space before 0. Alle elements are shiftet to the right so that 0 is free for inserting the new element. Is the same as if you would insert an element at index 3. There is also no "space" between 2 and 3 but the current element at 3 is moved to 4 and after this index 3 is free for the new element.

Answer (score 1):

Slice assignment doesn't *insert* so much as it *replaces*. You can think of any assignment like

```
L[x:y] = z
```

where `0 <= x <= y`* as being the same as

```
L = L[:x] + z + L[y:]
```

except `L` is modified in place, rather than a new list being created. In particular,

- If `z` is shorter than the target slice, the list becomes shorter
- If `z` is longer than the target lice, the list becomes larger

When you assign to `x[:0]`, you "replace" the empty slice at the start of the list with the contents of `y`, without affecting the elements in `x[0:]` (i.e., the entire original list.) Using the semantics above, you can say that `x[:0] = y` is equivalent to `x[:0] + y + x[0:]` == y + x`, but in-place.

---

* The semantics can be expanded for arbitrary `x` and `y`, but that didn't seem necessary for this answer.